What is the intuition behind designing a neural network for complex non-linear regression problems?
What is the intuition behind designing a neural network for complex non-linear regression problems?
I'm looking for guidance on how to intuitively design a neural network for regression, specifically when dealing with complex non-linear functions. I understand the basic structure of neural networks, but I'm unsure about how to determine the number of layers, the number of units per layer, the choice of activation functions, and the preprocessing techniques to use.
For example, consider the following complex function:
Let x1,x2,x3....xn be the inputs 
  y1 = x1 + x2*x3 - x4^2 - x5/x6 
  y2 = max(x7,x8,x9) if x10 == 1 else min(x11,x12,x13) 
  y3 = 1 if x14>x15/x16 else 0 
  y4 = ........
  .............
Y = y1 + y2*y3 - y4/y5......

Solve for Y given inputs x1,x2,x3....xn

What should be my intuition behind designing the neural network and preprocessing pipeline to model such a function?
For instance, I know that using polynomial features from sklearn can help in preprocessing by transforming the inputs to include interaction terms. But beyond that, how do I decide on the specific structure of the network and the preprocessing techniques?
How do I determine the right activation functions and the number of hidden layers?
(Maybe I need to have a certain activation function at a certain layer for some certain reason?)
I'm seeking a logical reasoning behind each decision to effectively model non-linear regression. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I don't want to perform trial and error, I also don't want to try things randomly until something works.
I am looking for specific reasoning for each specific preprocessing step and model architecture.
